# Creating/persisting new document while preUpdate event in doctrine-mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm, odm, doctrine-mongodb

I'm using `doctrine-mongodb-odm-1.0.0-BETA10` and trying to provide some custom logic based on `\InitialDocument` while `preUpdate` event running.

Lets say `\InitialDocument` obtained some state which must behave as initial one for new `\StateDocument`. I'm doing something like this:

```
class InitDocListener implements \Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber {
    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            Events::preUpdate
        ];
    }

    public function preUpdate($args){
        $document = $args->getDocument();
        if($document instanceOf InitialDocument && $document->getState() == 'mine'){
            $stateDocument = new \StateDocument();
            $stateDocument->setInitDocument($document);
            $args->getDocumentManager()->persist($stateDocument);
            //no flush cause recursion happens
        }
    }

}
```

`prePersist` event by `\StateDocument` happens, but it will not persist new document in db. and `postPersist` event accordingly will never be fired.

There is some more custom logic but all in event scope. At some point that logic may throw an Exception which must stop update event of `InitialDocument` so `InitialDocument` state depends of `\StateDocument` creation process at business scope.

How can I solve this problem? `preFlush` event to run before changeSet recalculation do not determine `InitialDocument` instance. So it is some kind of trick to "search" updates at `preFlush` and cause me to think it is not proper way. Please advise me in proper one. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I created a test case for your use case [here](https://gist.github.com/jmikola/7dff669cddf96cea3f30). One thing that stood out from the code in your question was that you weren't calling `recomputeSingleDocumentChangeSet()` on the document you were modifying during the lifecycle callback, as is mentioned in the [`preUpdate` documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate). But even with that call, the new document will not be inserted. This is due to the fact that UnitOfWork executes updates *after* insertions and upserts. The full order can be seen in [UnitOfWork's `commit()` method](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/dc4730329a028c0c5e5034db61fa432868e8b3df/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/UnitOfWork.php#L423):

- Document upserts
- Document inserts
- Document updates
- Extra updates (scheduled internally by persister classes)
- Collection deletions
- Collection updates
- Document deletions

When the `preUpdate` event is dispatched, upserts/inserts for new documents have already happened. Even with a call to `recomputeSingleDocumentChangeSet()`, you end up scheduling the document for insertion but UnitOfWork ignores this and ultimately unsets it when clearing out all of the schedule queues [here](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/dc4730329a028c0c5e5034db61fa432868e8b3df/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/UnitOfWork.php#L481).

While a simple solution would be for ODM to check for additional inserts after processing updates, that could lead to an infinite loop in some situations. The UnitOfWork ordering predates my work on the project, but I the risk of looping might have been a concern when the original implementation was conceived.

As a work-around, you may want to have the listener dump the new documents to be inserted into some other container (or the listener itself) and then check after the fact for additional documents to be persisted/flushed.

Comment: Thank you. I was playing some time with UnitOfWork yesterday and came to similar conclusions. You've just confirmed the assumption that at that case we need to handle insertion documents in some other container. Problem with that is that `preUpdate` event cause MANAGED state for new document persisted at that time and after commit `//Clear up` its upsertions (and other stuff). Document left known and stated as MANAGED but it cause an errors during new persist/flush on that document.

Comment: So I've tried to wrap `flush()` to handle own custom event `afterCommit` (after `clear up`) and add scheduleForUpsert again to prevent doing `persist()`. But it did not work. Now i'm trying to abandon `preUdpate` in favor of my `afterCommit` totally. Will bring some (failover?) tests if issue will be approved to come in GitHub.

Comment: After all. Decided to abandon `preUpdate` event in favor of wrapped flush and implemented `afterCommit` event with rollback behavior if new document persistence app logic emits failures. Queue: 1. `preUpdate` validates initial documents and makes changesSet for rollbacks. 2.`afterUpdate` makes documents attached to `updated_docs collection`. 3 `afterCommit` event trigger creation of new documents based on `updated_docs_collection` and flush them or rollback updated docs on failure. Not a good one implementation but works for now.